# "NullPointerException" getActivity().findViewById return null on Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, findviewbyid

I have a problem updating menu items of my Activity from a Fragment after an interstitial banner is closed (using "X" or clicking "back" it's the same).
Before android HONEYCOMB everything works well also after interstitial banner, maybe because I use android.support.v4.app.Fragment.

in my activity with this layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/menuContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I add a new fragment and everyting goes fine:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragments, MyFragment.newInstance());
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

This is Fragment code:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance() {
    return new MyFragment();
}
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

private View mSimpleContainer;
private TextView mSimpleText;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);

    mSimpleContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.mSimpleContainer);
    mSimpleText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.simpleText);

    return view;
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mSimpleText.setText("lorem ipsum");

    MyActivity act = (MyActivity) getActivity();

    if (act != null) {
        HorizontalScrollView menu = (HorizontalScrollView) act.findViewById(R.id.menuContainer);

        /**
        * menu is null and I get NullPointerException here after interstitial is closed.
        * Maybe the activity is paused and resumed but I expect that in onActivityCreated the activity is attached
        */
        menu.hideMenuItems();

        //This line open an Interstitial banner that when it's closed causes NullPointerException above
        act.showInterstitial(); //If I comment this line everything works fine
    }
}
```

When it's the correct time to call findViewById in the activity?
Thanks for any answers

Comment: Write this is onActivityCretaed():
  mSimpleContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.mSimpleContainer);
    mSimpleText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.simpleText);

Comment: And simpleText will actually have to refer to a TextView with id simpleText

Comment: I get NPE on menu.hideMenuItems(); because menu is null after interstitial is closed, but I don't understand why

Comment: should  a.findViewByID  actually be  act.findViewById  I cannot see where you are defining the object named "a"

Comment: Yes you don't have *a* define, just the *act*

Comment: sorry I renamed var "a" to "act" it was copy/paste mistake, when I posted the question

Comment: typecast getActivity()

Answer (score 1):

I think you r switching many fragment in the fragments FrameLayout. In that case the fragments are showing and hiding. So if any memory shortage occur fragmentManger is destroying invisible  fragments view, but the are still attached to activity. so getActivity() is not returning null, but view is returning null. In this situation you will call getView(), if getView() return null then your fragments view is destroyed by fragmentManager , otherwise call getView().findViewById() it will return you valid view object. There is no problem in support.v4 fragment. May be FragmentManager of support.v4 are more memory concious.

Comment: getView() will return the fragment view is correct? So my problem is to access a view inside the main activity. So I think that if getView() is not null, getView().findViewById(R.id.menuContainer) will always return null because R.id.menuContainer is not in the fragment view, but in activity

Comment: MyActivity act = (MyActivity) getActivity();

    if (act != null) {
        HorizontalScrollView menu = (HorizontalScrollView)    act.findViewById(R.id.menuContainer);
        menu.hideMenuItems();


        act.showInterstitial();
}
put it in OnCreateView() in the fragment.

Comment: The problem is still here, i noticed that happens also if I click the home button and then I restore the app.